# How do I get the item count (size) of a dojo datastore?

Tags: dojo

I don't see anything in the read API that provides access to this:
http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dojo.data.api.Read

Comment: With dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore you can do:

myStore._getItemsArray().length

But this is particular to that data store. I'm wondering what the correct way to get store size is.

Comment: This method is even more hackish than I initially thought. The array isn't initialized until fetch is called. So you have to make sure you fetch before checking the array length.

>>> store._getItemsArray().length
0
>>> store.fetch()
Object store=Object
>>> store._getItemsArray().length
2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the wire-data of any data store is completely store-specific.  In order for you to get the total items count (and other metadata), it must be returned as part of the response.  This is the only way to do server-side pagination.

All the stores I have implemented expect the data to contain a `totalCount` attribute, like so:

```
{
  identifier: 'id',
  items: [
    { id: 123, name: 'aaa', ... },
    { id: 456, name: 'bbb', ... },
    ...
  ],
  totalCount: 525
}
```

The store saves this when the query returns (in `onComplete`).  The value is then exposed via a `getTotalCount()` method on the store.

When used in conjunction with the `start` and `count` request options, this allows you to have nice ajax pagination ("Showing 1-50 of 525").

Since this is not part of the API, the core implementations of the read API do not implement it.  A form of this technique (similar to what I have done) does seem to be implemented by the `dojo.data.QueryReadStore`, so you can probably look there also.

Answer (score 8):

An example at [dojocampus](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/api/Read) demonstrates one way. Here a `fetch` without `query` parameter returns all the items in the store.

```
var store = new some.Datastore();
var gotItems = function(items, request){
  console.log("Number of items located: " + items.length);
};
store.fetch({onComplete: gotItems});
```

Answer (score 2):

dojo.data.api.Read's onBegin function has the total size of the match:

```
function size(size, request){
  // Do whatever with the size var.
}

store.fetch({query: {}, onBegin: size, start: 0, count: 0});
```

From this quickstart: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/faq.html#question-6-how-do-i-get-a-count-of-all-items-in-a-datastore

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this question using the JsonRest store, and this seems to be it:

> On your server, you should look 
>   at the Range header in the request to know which items to return. The
>   server should respond with a Content-Range header to indicate how many
>   items are being returned and how many total items exist:
>
> ```
> Content-Range: items 0-24/66
> ```

From: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store/JsonRest.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```
  // questionStoreReader is a pointer that points to and can read ask.json file

  var questionStoreReader=new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url:"ask.json"});

  questionStoreReader.fetch(
   {
     onComplete:function(items,request) // items is an array
      {
        alert(items.length);// number of items in ask.json
      },
   })
```